# downgrade from Android 4.xx to 2.xx

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, htc, htc-wildfire, htc-incredible-s

can we down grade Android from 4.x to 2.x?? if I bought Android 4 device and need to downgrad it to Android 2.xx, can I do that ?

the devices are HTC with these modules:

•HTC devices especially the Incredible

•HTC Wildfire running CyanogenMod

•HTC Desire

•HTC Wildfire running CyanogenMod 6.1.0

but when I buy them they will have Android 4.X

Comment: Why is Android 2.x a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the device, and what you mean by "2.xx". Do you want **A:** stock Android? **B:** a ROM? **C:** a manufacturer-skinned stock image?

I'm going to assume that the answer do the question above is **D:** Any of the above. I'm also going to assume that by "2.xx", you mean **2.3**. There are a few general requirements that will need to be fulfilled for it to be practical, and remember that *this depends on the device and software*; do your research before buying (assuming you haven't bought already).

**The requirements:**

**1:** The device was launched with Android 2.3 or earlier.

**2:** The device has an unlocked, unencrypted (or unlockable) bootloader.

**3:** (Pseudo-requirement) The device had, at the time that Android 2.3 was still important, an active development community.

**If you meet the requirements:**

You will have to do some google searching for various solutions. If you want...

**A stock device image** (not stock/"pure" Android) then you can find instructions generally by searching "unroot [device name]" on Google and XDA Developers.

**A ROM**: Go to XDA Developers or the popular dev community site for the device (Google is your friend) and search for CyanogenMod 7, or any other 2.3 ROM.

**Stock Android**: Good luck. I don't think you'll be able to find any flashable images with stock Android 2.3 for non-nexus devices.

Comment: well I don't know what are differences between them,
but need for having android 2.3 on these devices, also I need to root it

Comment: CyanogenMod comes rooted. You want either 6 or 7. XDA is your friend.

Comment: then it is seems to be as same procedure to install any Rom on device ?

Comment: The procedure for installing each ROM can be different. Quite often, you can simply flash it using a custom recovery and it "just works". Sometimes (for older/obscure devices) you might have to do something else.